# How to insert a character in between youtube Json link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I am getting `json` data from a link and in this link youtube format is `http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=UVKsd8z6scw`   but i need letter "`v`" to be added in between this link to display it in iframe. then the link should look like `http:\/\/www.youtube.com\v/watch?v=UVKsd8z6scw`   format. How can i add character in this link using Jquery to display youtube video?

```
//jquery
//http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=UVKsd8z6scw should change to http:\/\/www.youtube.com\v/watch?v=UVKsd8z6scw
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",function(data){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));

    var content='';

    $.each(data,function(index,item){
      content +='<div class="userdata">';

      content +='<div class="userurl">'+item.keywords+'</div>';
      content +='<iframe class="usevideourl" src="'+item.videourl+'"></iframe>';
      content +='<img src="'+item.thumb+'" class="userimage"></img>';
      content +='</div>';
    });

    $('#dictionary').append(content);
  });   
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean a back-slash (`youtube.com\v/`) and not a front-slash (`youtube.com/v/`)?

Comment: @Philipp i am sure Philipp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript substr function to acquire the part "/watch?v=UVKsd8z6scw" of the url and then append it with "http://www.youtube.com\v" as shown below. Hope this helps. :)

```
       $.each(data,function(index,item){
            content +='<div class="userdata">';
            var received_url=item.videourl;
            var first_part = "http://www.youtube.com\\v";
            var second_part = received_url.substr(22,url.length);
            var edited_url=first+second;
            content +='<div class="userurl">'+item.keywords+'</div>';
            content +='<iframe class="usevideourl" src="'+edited_url+'"></iframe>';
            content +='<img src="'+item.thumb+'" class="userimage"></img>';
            content +='</div>';
        });
```

Comment: u've taken var received_url=item.videourl; and again first,second parts. combined in edited url. but wat happened to received_url? how did u link this received and edited?

Comment: sorry my bad. I edited my answer, it should be working now :)

Comment: second_part takes "/watch?v=UVKsd8z6scw" part from  received_url and combines with first_part.